# Python - Scipy: multivariate_normal - select the right subsets of input

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Any help that pushes me towards the right solution is greatly appreciated...

I am trying to do a classification in two steps:

1.) Calculate mu, sigma, and pi on the training set.
2.) Create a test routine, that takes

```
- mu, sigma, pi
- an array of Feature IDs
- testx and testy.
```

Part 1.) works. It returns
    - mu  # shape 4,13
    - sigma # shape 4,13,13
    - pi # shape 4,

```
def fit_generative_model(x,y):
    k = 3  # labels 1,2,...,k
    d = (x.shape)[1]  # number of features
    mu = np.zeros((k+1,d))
    sigma = np.zeros((k+1,d,d))
    pi = np.zeros(k+1)
    for label in range(1,k+1):
        indices = (y == label)
        mu[label] = np.mean(x[indices,:], axis=0)
        sigma[label] = np.cov(x[indices,:], rowvar=0, bias=1)
        pi[label] = float(sum(indices))/float(len(y))
    return mu, sigma, pi
```

**Part 2.) does not work, as I seem to be unable to select the right subsets of mu and sigma**

```
def test_model(mu, sigma, pi, features, tx, ty):
    mu, sigma, pi = fit_generative_model(trainx,trainy)
    # set the variables
    k = 3 # Labels 1,2,...,k
    nt = len(testy)
    score = np.zeros((nt,k+1))
    covar = sigma
    for i in range(0,nt):
        for label in range(1,k+1):
            score[i,label] = np.log(pi[label]) + \
            multivariate_normal.logpdf(testx[i,features], mean=mu[label,:], cov=covar[label,:,:])
    predictions = np.argmax(score[:,1:4], axis=1) + 1

    errors = np.sum(predictions != testy)

return errors
```

It should return the number of mistakes made by the generative model on the test data when restricted to the specified features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should work.

`mean=mu[label,features], cov=covar[label,features,features]`

Answer (score 0):

this works for selecting 1, 2, and all feature(s). But when selecting three, it gives an overestimate. In another forum, they say that when `covar[label,fetures,fetures]` (when features = [2,4,6]), this will result in `[2,2],[4,4],[6,6]` instead of a 3*3 matrix.

Unfortunately, the other forum does not provide the answer.

Comment: While posted as an answer, it really does not appear to be one. Perhaps you should ask a new question instead?